# Select All CheckBoxes from single CheckBox in VBA on PowerPoint

Tags: vba, checkbox, powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint to create UI mockups and have enabled the developer tools that create premade checkboxes, etc. I want to have a single checkbox that when selected, selects all the others on the slide.

I have tried the following code, which is accepted syntactically, but does nothing visibly.

this is a modified version from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2692-excel-checkbox-select-all.html

CheckBox11 is my "Select All" check box and CheckBox 1-10 need to be selected or deselected based on it being clicked.

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()
    Dim xCheckBox As CheckBox
    For Each xCheckBox In Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Checkboxes
        If xCheckBox.Name <> Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Checkboxes("Check Box 11").Name Then
            xCheckBox.Value = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Checkboxes("Check Box 11").Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox11_()
     SelectAll_Click
End Sub
```

How can I get this checkbox to check or uncheck the rest on the slide?

Comment: A `Slide` object doesn't have a `Checkboxes` property. The Powerpoint Object Model is different from Excel...

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Kind of a naive solution but

```
Private Sub SelectAll()
If CheckBox11.Value = True Then
    CheckBox1.Value = True
    CheckBox2.Value = True
    CheckBox3.Value = True
    CheckBox4.Value = True
    CheckBox5.Value = True
    CheckBox6.Value = True
    CheckBox7.Value = True
    CheckBox8.Value = True
    CheckBox9.Value = True
    CheckBox10.Value = True
End If
If CheckBox11.Value = False Then
    CheckBox1.Value = False
    CheckBox2.Value = False
    CheckBox3.Value = False
    CheckBox4.Value = False
    CheckBox5.Value = False
    CheckBox6.Value = False
    CheckBox7.Value = False
    CheckBox8.Value = False
    CheckBox9.Value = False
    CheckBox10.Value = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox11_Click()
    SelectAll
End Sub
```